# Maximize browser window on Mac?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

`current_window.maximize` works on Windows but on Mac, I end up starting in a window around 1200x725. Is there a way to maximize the window for both Windows and Mac without having to use `window.resize_to()`?